# Set right gravity to a message inside a ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to set a right gravity to a message inside my ProgressDialog.
I've tried to:

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
dialog.setMessage(loadDialogMessage);
```

But still the gravity of the message is set to the right.
How can I do that ?

Comment: loadDialogMessage is a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick :

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
dialog.setMessage("42 is the answer to life the universe and everything");
dialog.show();
TextView tvMessage = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
tvMessage.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

I just looked at the source http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/ProgressDialog.java#147
and look at the textview's id

Comment: How about the title?