# How to change the positioning of a ProgressDialog?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am using a simple progress dialog. I would like to change progress from left to right.

```
ProgressDialog dialog = null ; //global var

dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Register.this, "", "arabic words");
                            dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

[image]

how can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the message and not the direction the loading icon spins. If so, try targeting the text instead of the dialog:

```
TextView message = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
message.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

From here: [Set right gravity to a message inside a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320139/set-right-gravity-to-a-message-inside-a-progressdialog)

Comment: is there no way to change loading icon to right side ?

Comment: Try finding the spinner/progress bar's view (e.g. `spinner` instead of `message` in my above example) and setting the gravity on that. I'm unable to test at the moment, so the view might not actually be called `spinner`, but I think that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.right_spin, null);
        TextView txt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        txt.setText("arabic words");
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setContentView(v);
    }
```

right_spin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >


      <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_margin="16dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
         android:layout_margin="16dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/progress" />

</RelativeLayout>
```